# Making a DIV work with hover and as a link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

I am trying to make a div, that changes behaviour when you hover (inverts the colour of background and logo) and is also a link.

I have managed to get these two behaviours (act as a link and invert colours) to work correctly, but only independently - I cannot get the two to work together.

I suspect it is because of the span tag which makes the link, but cannot be sure:

```
.full_box a span {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1
}
```

You can see my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/omcoombs/4pbpto2z/

Thanks in advance

Comment: I should say - I have commented out the link in the analysis div, you can see if you uncomment it out how the hover doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add your `div` **inside** the `a` element, it will work. Example:

```css
.big-box {  
  background: cyan;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}

.big-box a {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.small-box {
  background: white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.small-box:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-box">
  <a href="about:blank">
    <div class="small-box">
      logo or sg
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: OK thanks - i'll give it a go, although i actually managed to fix it too!

Comment: Always the way, I spend hours mucking about on it, then as soon as i ask the question, i fix it. Thanks anyway.